# Unable to link react-native-version-number

Tags: npm, react-native

I am trying to install `react-native-version-number`. The [instructions](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-version-number) state that after installing, issue;

```
react-native link react-native-version-number
```

but when I do this, I get the following error message;

```
Looks like you installed react-native globally, maybe you meant react-native-cli?
To fix the issue, run:
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

but when I run

```
npm uninstall -g react-native
```

I get

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "react-native"
```

How do I link react-native-version-number?

Comment: rnpm link? (if you have rnpm installed)

Comment: did you run react-native link from the project root?

Comment: I just checked, I definitely ran it from the root.

Comment: dv3: rnpm link did work.  If you write an answer along those lines, then I will accept it. It would be a better answer if you explain why react-native link does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, dv3's comment about using `rnpm link` did work. However, I found that I was having this problem with other react-native commands, such as `react-native run-android`. This appears to be because npm was installed using homebrew. A description of this problem and how to fix it can be found at on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689).  In summary the required fix is to uninstall all your npm globably installed packages, uninstall node, then reinstall node, and reinstall npm without brew.

```
npm list -g --depth=0 # to list all your globally installed packages
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

and then, you have to reinstall all your npm packages that were installed globally.